# Work item not showing up in VSTS backlog or board

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I've created a task, assigned most properties (including iteration) and saved it. However it's not showing in the backlog or board.

I've manually set it to Active. But to no avail.

Originally the task was the child to another task. The parent task was also in the same iteration (but not showing up)

This is not the only work item that does not show up anywhere.

Any reason why?

**EDIT**

The task and user story are added to the backlog and board if the Area is, for example `MyProject`. If the area is 'MyProject/Modules/Customers', the task and user story do not show up.

Why is this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It’s usually caused by **the parent task is unparented**. The parent task only child task as related work, and there is no parent PBI or user stories etc as below graph.

[image]

For backlog and Board, they show the WITs related for PBI/user stories/Bugs. Since the tasks are not related to PBI/user stories/Bugs, so the unparented tasked won’t show in backlog and Board.

To let the tasks show in the backlog and Board, you should add PBI/user story/Bug as the parent for the parent task.

[image]

And the tasks, they usually in the same hierarchy (not parent-child relations). Please check the tasks, if they should not be parent-child relation, you can remove the relations in **Related Work**.

#### Reason for why the area with MyProject\Modules\Customers not show in backlog and board:

Only the selected areas will show in your team’s backlog and Board.

And the areas Modules and Customers are not added in your team. You can check in the page https://account.visualstudio.com/MyProject/_admin/_Work?_a=areas, as below screen shot, there has no team related to the sub area.

[image]

To add the Modules and Customers in your team, you can follow below steps:

- Go to Default team settings (https://account.visualstudio.com/MyProject/MyProject%20Team/_admin)

  [image]
- Work Tab -> Areas -> Select area(s) -> add the sub area(s) -> select Include sub areas -> save and close.

  [image]
- After adding all the child areas, go to the package https://account.visualstudio.com/MyProject/_admin/_Work?_a=areas, you you will find there are team related to the child areas.

  [image]
- And in the backlog and board, the WIT with the area MyProject\Modules\Customers will be showed.

Comment: I've added a User Story as the task's parent. Neither the story nor the task is shown in the backlog or board. On the other hand, I have unparented tasks that do show in the backlog and board!!

Comment: Can you add the screen shot for the user story which added as the task's parent?

Comment: I updated my question as to why the task and user story are now showing in the board and backlog.

Comment: I added the reason why the WIT with MyProject\Modules\Customers area can be showed in backlog and board. And give the detail setting to show the WIT. More details, you can refer in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found that some items in the "New" column of a board were not being shown on page load. To fix this, I had to click on the "Find more items online" button.

To show the hidden items, this text will need to be clicked every time you load the page. Confirmed in the 2017 version of VSTS / TFS.

[image]

Comment: This solved it for me - the items and their tags in "New" weren't filterable until I clicked the magnifying glass and "found" some of them. The client might only be loading the first 50 or so items into the page, and you have to "find" them to make them appear on screen and be usable.... very confusing!

Answer (score 0):

Tasks don't show up in the *Backlog Items* view, user stories/PBIs/Bugs (configurable) do.

Assuming the task is part of an iteration, you should see it under *Unparented* on the task board for that iteration. In order for it to be parented, it has to be the child of a PBI/User Story or a (Bug if you have bugs as requirements configured).

Comment: The task is unparented and part of an iteration. It doesn't show up on the board for the iteration.

Comment: Yes it's in the correct area. Also, when I click on Queries, it's also not visible in the first list displayed.